# What online tools exist for creating home wiring diagrams?

Tags: discussion

In the Q&A [Request Support for CircuitLab schematic editor](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/request-support-for-circuitlab-schematic-editor), I disagreed with the proposal to use [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) for creating wiring diagrams.

But that raises the question if there is an app that would be better suited for that purpose. I don't know of any so wanted to crowd-source the question.

Some requirements that I thought of (there may be more, please comment if you think of any):

1. Online, can be embedded in a post on DIY.SE.
2. Stores the diagram state within the post so that it can be saved and edited, or copied from a question into an answer.
3. Provides conventional symbols for home wiring diagrams.
4. Reasonable cost (I don't know how much it costs SE to use CircuitLab, but presumably the cheaper it is the more likely they'd approve it).
5. Bonus: can also be used for other types of diagrams: floorplans, plumbing, gas, etc.

Comment: MSPaint, though I don't think Microsoft has moved that program to the cloud yet.

Comment: Related but not necessarily a suitable answer:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/41877/246